# Как в си реализовать структуру формату XY которая будет брать из x номер строки в файле, а из Y индекс char символа который нужно получить?

Tags: c

столкнулся с небольшим затруднением в реализации нужной функции.
Мне нужно сверять все строки из файла(размер файла от 1 до 10к строк) с конкретным символом, и если строка содержит этот самый символ. Записать его координаты в формате XY, и на выходе получить int значение которое содержит количество указанных символов. А так же координаты каждого из них для дальнейшей обработки. (Если конкретно: нужно будет найти максимально возможную площадь квадрата между указанными символами ориентируясь на полученные координаты формата XY)
И основная рпоблема заключается как раз в том что я никак не могу понять как именно реализовать переход по строками координаты Y в зависимости от их.
Например в в двух строках
qwerty
ytrewq
я не могу понять как прописав 
sq.x = 2;
sq.y = 1; получить букву t(вторая строка, индекс char 1)

примерный демо код на котором я пытался реализовать это ниже. К сожалению у меня ничего не вышло, но буду очень признателен хотябы за наводки в какую сторону копать по данной теме.
Заранее благодарю.

```
void    ft_sear_sq(char *maps, int max_x, int max_y, char p) 
{
    typedef struct s_coord
    {
        int x;
        int y;
    }               t_coord;
    t_coord sq;
    int i;
    int max_pl;
    int kol_pr;

    sq.x = 1;
    sq.y = 0;
    kol_pr = 0;
    i = 0;

while (sq.x < max_x)//считаю количество препятствий
{
    while (maps[sq.y] != '\n')
    {
        if (maps[sq.y] == p)
            kol_pr++;
            sq.y++;
    }
    sq.x++;
    sq.y = 0; //как сдвигать sq.y вниз на сторчку в зависимости от х?
}
max_pl = (max_x * max_y) - kol_pr;
max_pl = ft_kor(max_pl);
sq.x = 1;
sq.y = 0;
while (i < (max_pl * max_pl))
{
    if (maps[sq.y] != p)//сдвигаю sq.y пока он не равен символу ограничителю
    {
        sq.y++;
        i++;
    }
    else//в случе если квадрат на поместился, уменьшаю его площадь на 1, и повторяю пока не найду квадрат, который поместится.
    {
        max_pl--;
        i = 0;
        sq.x = 1;
        sq.y = 0;
    }
    if (maps[sq.y] == '\n')
    {
        sq.y = 0;//та же проблема, как сдвинуть ось Y на нужную строчку, в зависимости от x?
        sq.x++;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Самое простое `strptr = fgets(..)` получить строку, потом в цикле `for` пройтись по массиву символов, используя функцию `strchr(..)`, она же вернёт позицию в строке. Посчитать номер символа: `(return strchr() - strptr - 1)`

Comment: Самое правильное, сделать матрицу на 256 (массив), и проходить в цикле посимвольного разбора строки через эту матрицу, в матрице нужные символы отмечены например `true`, остальные `false`.

Comment: Вам не нужны две координаты - достаточно одной - offset'а от начала файла. Вторую координату, если она действительно нужна, Вы всегда можете рассчитать исходя из выбранной длины строки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct map_t
{
    size_t line;
    size_t col;
} map_t;

map_t *find_char(FILE *fp, int c, size_t *qty)
{
    size_t line = 0;
    size_t col  = 0;
    size_t size = 8;
    size_t idx  = 0;

    map_t *char_map = malloc(sizeof(map_t) * size);

    if (!char_map)
        return NULL;    

    int ch;
    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        if (ch == '\n')
        {
            line++, col = 0;
            continue;
        }

        if (ch == c)
        {
            if (idx == size)
            {
                map_t *tmp = realloc(char_map, (size *= 2) * sizeof(map_t));
                if (!tmp)
                {
                    free(char_map);
                    return NULL;
                }
                char_map = tmp;
             }
             char_map[idx++] = (map_t){.line = line, .col = col};
        }
        col++;
    }
    *qty = idx;
    return char_map;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <char>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    size_t qty;
    map_t *res = find_char(stdin, *argv[1], &qty);
    if (!res)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "memory allocation error\n");
        return 2;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < qty; i++)
        printf("y: %zu, x: %zu\n", res[i].line, res[i].col);

    printf("qty: %zu\n", qty);
    free(res);
    return 0;
}
```